# Insert a background image in CSS (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i add a image background to my website?

```
body {
     margin: 0;
     background: url(background.png);
     background-size: 1440px 800px;
     background-repeat:no-repeatdisplay: compact;
     font: 13px/18px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

I did that much but nothing shows up on my page. I'm a CSS beginner.

Updated:

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 background-image: url(.../img/background.jpg);
 background-size: 1440px 800px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 display: compact;
 font: 13px/18px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Put the background url in quotes.

It should be `background: url('background.png');`

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h8SBh/1/) for working demo.

You also have an issue with the `background-repeat line` missing a semicolon in between two statements. If your background is really tiny you won't see it because of that issue.

Just to update on the solution, among the other issues, the background file was being refrenced with `.../background.jpg` when it should have been `../background.jpg` (2 dots, not 3).

Comment: Does the background image in my demo work? Replace the url of your image with the Google logo I used and see if that works. Maybe you have a large div covering up the body or something.. care to share your html along with any other css you have?

Comment: The demo code worked fine. Maybe i should use a URL? is there way to upload an attachment?

Comment: The URL is relative to your CSS file. So if you have styles/mycss.css and images/mybackground.jpg it should be `../images/mybackground.jpg` (only two dots, not 3 like you have). Also don't forget the closing brace `}` at the end.

Comment: Ohh wow, It worked. Thank You. I had no idea the dots had something to do with the location. So, just to make clear, every dot for every folder in go in?

Comment: No, `.` is current directory so `./myfile` is in the current working directory. `../` is "go up one directory" so `../myfile` is a file named `myfile` one level above this one. So if you're in `mysite/css/mycss.css` then `../myfile` is `/mysite/myfile`. One dot is current directory, two dots go up a directory. You can keep it up with `../../` to go up two directories and so on.

Answer (score 6):

isn't the problem the following line is incorrect as the statement for `background-repeat` isn't closed before the next statement for `display`...

```
background-repeat:no-repeatdisplay: compact;
```

Shouldn't this be

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display: compact;
```

adding or removing quotes (in my experience) makes no difference if the URL is correct. Is the path to the image correct? **If you give a relative path to a resource in a CSS it's relative to the CSS file, not the file including the CSS.**

Answer (score 2):

Is your image on the same folder/directory as your css file? If so, your image url is correct. Otherwise, it's not.

If by any chance your folder structure is like so...

webpage 
-index.html
-css
- - style.css
- images
- - background.png

then to reference the image on your css file you should use the following path:

../images/background.png

So that would be background: url('../images/background.png');

The logic is simple: Go up one folder by typing "../" (as many times as you need). Go down one folder by specifying the folder you wish to go down to.

Comment: I tried everything ...my location is correct too. But, no luck.

Comment: what's the display: compact in there for?

Comment: it's not the "display: compact" i was just wondering why you're using it. I don't think you need it. Is there no typo on your image name? Is there not an element covering your body background with it's own background?

Answer (score 2):

Adding background image on html, body or a wrapper element to achieve background image will cause problems with padding. Check this ticket https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3169 on github. ShaunR's comment and also one of the creators response to this. The given solution in created ticket doesn't solve the problem, but it at least gets things going if you aren't using responsive features.

Assuming that you are using container without responsive features, and have a width of 960px, and want to achieve 10px padding, you set:

```
.container {
   min-width: 940px;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following you can set the background colour or image
(your css)

```
 html { 
     background-image: url('http://yoursite/i/tile.jpg');
     background-repeat: repeat; 
 }

 .body {
     background-color: transparent; 
 }
```

This is because BS applies a css rule for background colour and also for the `.container` class.

Answer (score 1):

And if you can't repeat the background image (for esthetic reasons), 
then this handy JQuery plugin will stretch the background image to 
fit the window.

Backstretch
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Works great...

~Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    background-image: url(your image link);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #464646;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For more modularity and in case you have many background images that you want to incorporate wherever you want you can for each image create a class :

```
.background-image1  
{
background: url(image1.jpg);
 }
.background-image2  
{
background: url(image2.jpg);
 }
```

and then insert the image wherever you want by adding a div

```
<div class='background-image1'>
    <div class="page-header text-center", style='margin: 20px 0 0px;'>
         <h1>blabaaboabaon</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can also be the ordering of your style sheet imports. 
I had to move my custom style sheet import below the bootstrap import.